# Cannot connect to database with username and password

Tags: php, mysql

I just created a database by importing SQL file. I have created users added privileges but when I try to connect by PDO it throws this error:

> (Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user xxx)

even though the username and password is correct.

I am having hard time to solve this. I deleted the database and also created again another database but it seems nothing will work.

```
$host = "example.com";
$db = "sgOnlineSystem";
$user = "xxx";
$pass = "xxxx";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
```

I have no idea what's going wrong.
[image]

Comment: try printing error via mysql_error()

Comment: hi.. here is the mysql_error()   'Connection failed: Access denied for user 'admin0198'@'ip-160-153-162-20.ip.secureserver.net' (using password: YES)'

Comment: is your host set to `any` or  `ip-160-153-162-20.ip.secureserver.net` . [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: Francisco, try connecting as `root` with the known root password, to see if there are any other issues with your database server. You can also try connecting via the `mysql` console to eliminate any issues relating to PHP.

Comment: @halfer ok noted thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new user like that:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sgOnlineSystem.* TO 'admin0198'@'ip-160-153-162-20.ip.secureserver.net' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURPASSHERE';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES; // This is also important to do

--

And then just try to connect with command line tool from your remote host, not PHP. If it works than PHP code will work also.

Comment: hi. i am totally new to command line. if you could, please advise what to type in command line to connect. here is the actual/full error that shows. "Stack trace:
#0 /home/ry91p8weag4x/public_html/Conn.php(9): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=sg...', 'cajetan', 'hj03865684')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ry91p8weag4x/public_html/Conn.php on line 9"